# C++ vector parallel division

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing

I'm trying to enhance runtime of my code,
I'm using with std::vector with size that surpasses 2^18
I want to know if there a function(ality) that allows me to execute
scalar multiplication in parallel to all elements instead of going one by one?

Comment: Did you try `std::for_each` with different execution policies?

Comment: FWIW You should check your assembly.  Your compiler may be auto vectorizing the code for you if the loops are not to convoluted.

Comment: Why are you asking about parallel division if you want parallel scalar multiplication? Those two are two very different things.

Comment: Note that multiplying ~250 thousand values should be *memory bound* (with >=32-bit items data will likely be in the L3 on most machine if not the RAM). Memory bound code does not scale very well (the L3 cache can scale a bit though). Modern processors operating at 4 GHz can do that in sequential in at least 70 microseconds. If SIMD instructions can be used, then it should be only a faction of that. Creating threads and waiting them is generally much slower. Communicating with existing thread generally take 1-50 us. Parallelizing this should not help a lot.